# Draw jpeg array directly onto a Canvas

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

At the moment I get a byte array of a JPEG from my signalr connection and load it into a image and on the image.onload event I draw the image to my canvas.

so:

```
desktopImage.onload = function () {
    myCanvasContext.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0);
}

chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (jpeg) {
    desktopImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + jpeg;
}
```

Which does work well.

I was wondering whether i could 'quicken' this process by drawing the image directly onto the canvas without 1st loading it to an image 1st.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you receive a byte array as you state, assuming ArrayBuffer, you could wrap it as a Blob object and create an object URL for it instead. This will save significant overhead from encoding and decoding Base-64:

### Example:

```
var desktopImage = new Image();
var url;

desktopImage.onload = function () {
    myCanvasContext.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0);
    (URL || webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(url);  // release memory
}

// assuming jpeg = ArrayBuffer:
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (jpeg) {
    var blob = new Blob([jpeg], {type: "image/jpeg"});
    url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

    desktopImage.src = url;
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid Array object.

Comment: 'jpeg' is not null.  Is there a conversion O need to make from jpeg byte array to ArrayBuffer?

Comment: if you console.log(jpeg), what does console say?

Comment: snaphot: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMj

Comment: There is no object type of arrayBuffer in C# which is on my server end

Comment: @AndrewSimpson ok, that's not an ArrayBuffer.. in which case this won't work (it should have said: `ArrayBuffer { byteLength: n }`. If the data there is base-64 then the way you're doing it already is fastest as the browser will do the decoding. If you can make signalr transfer arraybuffer instead of base-64 you could have used the approach in the answer.. (ArrayBuffer on the server side would just be an ordinary  byte array, `byte[] array ...`)

Comment: hi, a jpeg image can only be converted to a byte array in 1 way?

Comment: I may need to post a new question :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson the other client can encode the Jpeg as a Blob (ie. canvas.toBlob()) which basically is ArrayBuffer/byte array. If signalr (long time since I tried it so i cannot remember) accept arraybuffer as transfer type, it could be handled as byte array on server side and transfered to second client as arraybuffer on client side.

Comment: OK, I will do some searching. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson lol. Yeah, it's getting a bit "out of scope". I'll delete this answer then :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson ok, I'll leave it as it is. .)